# How reliable is a 301 referer redirect? Are there any other alternatives?

Tags: http-status-code-301, http-referer

I need to be able to display 2 differing landing pages depending on the URL is user is coming from e.g. if user A comes from www.domain.com/qwe, he/she is redirected to page.domain.com and if user B comes from www.domain.com/rty he/she is redirected to page.domain.com. Depending on where they came from page.domain.com would show differing content. The redirection occurs as 310 redirect at the server level i.e. the web server implements the 301 redirect.

How reliable are 301 redirect referers?

Is there a better way to achieve the same result using a different method and if so what is it?

Comment: status codes & redirects are part of the HTTP specification, so I think it's reasonable to assume an HTTP-compliant client will follow them. Other options include HTML meta and JavaScript redirects, but then you are making assumptions that the client is a browser. If you don't mind the user's URL staying the same (e.g. domain.com/qwe) then use .htaccess or url rewrite at the server level

Comment: @tomfumb - Are the status codes passed as referers i.e. so when a redirect occurs from domain/qwe to page.domain.com, is the status code of a 301 redirect included as referer? Could you elaborate what you meant by "If you don't mind the user's URL staying the same (e.g. domain.com/qwe) then use .htaccess or url rewrite at the server level"?

Comment: with .htaccess the server can retrieve a different resource, for example if a user requests `site.com/blog/article/13/` .htaccess can actually execute `site.com/blog.php?articleId=13` or something similar. The URL in the user's browser still says `/blog/article/13` as there was no redirect - I believe this approach requires all the content is hosted on the same server

Comment: re your question on status codes as referrers I don't quite get it. In a normal HTTP request a response (e.g. HTML) is sent with 200 status code (OK) in the response headers, with an error the response has 500 code (internal server error). If you issue a 301 it is returned to the client in the header, with another header called 'location' which points to the desired resource, so the user's browser makes a whole new request to wherever you sent them

Comment: @tomfumb - Thanks tomfumb. That makes sense. Appreciate the help.